# Why isn't my sfml RectangleShape not showing on the window

Tags: c++, draw, sfml

I have a RectangleShape in my program that is supposed to show up somewhere but the RectangleShape is not showing for some reason. There are no errors in the program just the RectangleShape not showing. I have three files: main.cpp, button.h, and textbox.h. The RectangleShape is declared in the textbox.h header file. Here are the files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "button.h"
#include "textbox.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
static const float viewHeight = 500.f;
void resizeView(const RenderWindow &window, View &view){
    float aspectRatio = float(window.getSize().x) / float(window.getSize().y);
    view.setSize(viewHeight * aspectRatio, viewHeight);
}
int main(){
    View view(Vector2f(0.f, 0.f), Vector2f(viewHeight, viewHeight));
    Event event;
    bool isStartOpen = false;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(500, 500), "Operating System", Style::Close | Style::Resize);
    RectangleShape player(Vector2f(500.0f, 30.0f));
    RectangleShape startMenu(Vector2f(300.0f, 400.0f));
    Texture startTexture;
    if(!startTexture.loadFromFile("startButton.png")){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error loading image file: startButton.png in the system", "Image File Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    startMenu.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 200));
    startMenu.setPosition(0.0f, 500.0f);
    player.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    player.setPosition(0.0f, 473.0f);
    Font font;
    if(!font.loadFromFile("Calibri Regular.ttf")){
       MessageBox(NULL, "Error loading font file: buttonFont.ttf in the system", "Font File Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    Textbox passCreate(15, Color::Black, false, Color::White, 4, {100, 100});
    Button openNotepad("Notepad", {90, 90}, 14, Color::Green, startTexture, font);
    Button openCalc("Calculator", {90, 90}, 14, Color::Green, startTexture, font);
    Button startButton("", {30, 30}, 20, Color::White, startTexture, font);
    startButton.setPosition({0, 473});
    openNotepad.setPosition({0, 500});
    openCalc.setPosition({0, 500});
    passCreate.setFont(font);
    passCreate.setPosition({100, 100});
    passCreate.setLimit(true, 10);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Return)){
            passCreate.setSelected(true);
        }else if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)){
            passCreate.setSelected(false);
        }
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type){
                case Event::Resized:
                    resizeView(window, view);
                    break;
                case Event::TextEntered:
                    passCreate.typedOn(event);
                    break;
                case Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    cout << "Window has been removed" << endl;
                    break;
                case Event::MouseMoved:
                    if(openNotepad.isMouseOver(window)){
                        openNotepad.setBackColor(Color(42,150,83));
                        openNotepad.setOutThick(1.5f);
                        openNotepad.setOutColor(Color(255, 255, 255, 170));
                    }else{
                        openNotepad.setBackColor(Color(0,110,51));
                        openNotepad.setOutThick(0);
                    }if(openCalc.isMouseOver(window)){
                        openCalc.setBackColor(Color(42,150,83));
                        openCalc.setOutThick(1.5f);
                        openCalc.setOutColor(Color(255, 255, 255, 170));
                    }else{
                        openCalc.setBackColor(Color(0,110,51));
                        openCalc.setOutThick(0);
                    }if(startButton.isMouseOver(window)){
                        startButton.setBackColor(Color(1, 159, 255));
                    }else{
                        startButton.setBackColor(Color::White);
                    }
                    break;
                case Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                    if(openNotepad.isMouseOver(window)){
;                        system("notepad");
                    }else if(startButton.isMouseOver(window) && !isStartOpen){
                        startMenu.setPosition(0.f, 75.f);
                        openNotepad.setPosition({18, 90});
                        openCalc.setPosition({116, 90});
                        isStartOpen = true;
                    }else if(startButton.isMouseOver(window) && isStartOpen){
                        startMenu.setPosition(0.f, 500.f);
                        openNotepad.setPosition({0, 500});
                        openCalc.setPosition({0, 500});
                        isStartOpen = false;
                    }else if(openCalc.isMouseOver(window)){
                        system("calc");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        view.setCenter(250.f, 250.f);
        window.setView(view);
        window.draw(startMenu);
        passCreate.drawTo(window);
        window.draw(player);
        openNotepad.drawTo(window);
        openCalc.drawTo(window);
        startButton.drawTo(window);
        window.display();
        window.clear(Color(144, 0, 255));
    }
}
}
```

**button.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
class Button{
    public:
        Button(){

        }
        Button(string t, Vector2f size, int charSize, Color bgColor, Texture &texture, Font &font){
            text.setString(t);
            text.setColor(Color::White);
            text.setCharacterSize(charSize);
            text.setFont(font);
            button.setSize(size);
            button.setFillColor(bgColor);
            button.setPosition(0.f, 500.f);
            button.setTexture(&texture);
        }
        void setBackColor(Color color){
            button.setFillColor(color);
        }
        void setTextColor(Color color){
            text.setColor(color);
        }
        void setPosition(Vector2f pos){
            button.setPosition(pos);
            float yPos = (pos.y + button.getLocalBounds().height / 1.3);
            text.setPosition({pos.x + 5, yPos});
        }
        void drawTo(RenderWindow &window){
            window.draw(button);
            window.draw(text);
        }
        void setOutColor(Color outColor){
            button.setOutlineColor(outColor);
        }
        void setOutThick(float outThick){
            button.setOutlineThickness(outThick);
        }
        bool isMouseOver(RenderWindow &window){
            float mouseX = Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
            float mouseY = Mouse::getPosition(window).y;
            float btnPosX = button.getPosition().x;
            float btnPosY = button.getPosition().y;
            float btnxPosWidth = button.getPosition().x + button.getLocalBounds().width;
            float btnyPosWidth = button.getPosition().y + button.getLocalBounds().height;
            if(mouseX < btnxPosWidth && mouseX > btnPosX && mouseY < btnyPosWidth && mouseY > btnPosY){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    private:
       RectangleShape button;
       Text text;
};
```

**textbox.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#define DELETE_KEY 8
#define ENTER_KEY 13
#define ESCAPE_KEY 27
using namespace std;
class Textbox{
public:
    Textbox(){

    }
    Textbox(int size, Color textColor, bool sel, Color boxColor, int borderThick, Vector2f boxSize, Font &font, bool tof, int lim){
        textbox.setCharacterSize(size);
        textbox.setColor(textColor);
        textbox.setFont(font);
        hasLimit = tof;
        limit = lim - 1;
        typeArea.setFillColor(boxColor);
        typeArea.setOutlineThickness(borderThick);
        typeArea.setScale(boxSize);
        isSelected = sel;
        if(sel){
            textbox.setString("|");
        }else{
            textbox.setString("");
        }
        string passAttempt;
        string password;
        ifstream getPassword("password.txt");
        getline(getPassword, password);
        cout << "Enter your password";
        cin >> passAttempt;
        passAttempt.compare(password) == 0 ? cout << "correct password" : cout << "incorrect password";
        getPassword.close();
    }
    void setPosition(Vector2f pos){
        textbox.setPosition(pos);
        typeArea.setPosition(pos);
    }
    void setLimit(bool tof){
        hasLimit = tof;
    }
    void setSelected(bool sel){
        isSelected = sel;
        if(!sel){
            string t = text.str();
            string newT = "";
            for(int i = 0;i < t.length();i++){
                newT += t[i];
            }
            textbox.setString(newT);
        }
    }
    string getText(){
        return text.str();
    }
    void drawTo(RenderWindow &window){
        window.draw(textbox);
        window.draw(typeArea);
    }
    void typedOn(Event input){
        if(isSelected){
            int charTyped = input.text.unicode;
            if(charTyped < 128){
                if(hasLimit){
                    if(text.str().length() <= limit){
                        inputLogic(charTyped);
                    }else if(text.str().length() > limit && charTyped == DELETE_KEY){
                        deleteLastChar();
                    }
                }else{
                    inputLogic(charTyped);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void saveText(){
        if(isSelected){
            ofstream passFile("password.txt");
            passFile.is_open() ? MessageBox(NULL, "Sucessfully saved password", "Saved Password", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION) : MessageBox(NULL, "Error saving password: Password is in password.txt", "File Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            passFile << text.str();
            passFile.close();
        }
    }
private:
    Text textbox;
    RectangleShape typeArea;
    ostringstream text;
    bool isSelected = false;
    bool hasLimit = false;
    int limit;
    void inputLogic(int charTyped){
        if(charTyped != DELETE_KEY && charTyped != ENTER_KEY && charTyped != ESCAPE_KEY){
            text << static_cast<char>(charTyped);
        }else if(charTyped == DELETE_KEY){
            if(text.str().length() > 0){
                deleteLastChar();
            }
        }
        textbox.setString(text.str() + "|");
    }
    void deleteLastChar(){
        string t = text.str();
        string newT = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < t.length() - 1; i++){
            newT += t[i];
        }
        text.str("");
        text << newT;
        textbox.setString(text.str());
    }
};
```

Please help fix the program show the RectangleShape shows up

Comment: You pasted the code for button twice

Answer (score 1):

I loaded your project into my Code::Blocks environment, excluding textbox.h and calls to it. I replaced the image call with the original code::blocks logo cb.bmp. I chose a replacement font that was at hand.

When I compile the project, I find a taskbar-esque button, with two sub-buttons. Upon hovering the sub-buttons, a white border appears. Your *sf::RectangleShape* (that wasn't showing?) was called *button*.

Is this the intended behaviour?

If this is the intended behaviour, try rebuilding your project from scratch if you haven't already (delete all object files.) Perhaps this will let the compiler tell you if there's anything wrong it wasn't aware of.

Orphaned .o files (meaning they don't have a source file anymore) can cause a lot of trouble. Corresponding .o files are not deleted when deleting source files.

[image]

Comment: The rectangleShape is in textbox.h

Comment: Sorry for not putting the right code in the textbox.h segment

Comment: Try editing or commenting on your original post to clear up that you are not getting sf::RectangleShape typeArea in textbox.h to show up. We can't guess which sf::RectangleShape you are referring to. :)

Answer (score 1):

**After you updated your post:**
I found that

```
using namespace sf;
```

is not in your textbox.h

You also have two different include types of the SFML Graphics header

```
#include <SFML/graphics.hpp>
```

and

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

Assuming you have a stock install of SFML, the

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

Is usually the correct one.

**Tip:**
Using namespace calls can be quite risky, because you can forget where a function comes from. You can call commands from a namespace by prefixing your calls with the namespace name. For example:

```
RectangleShape typeArea;
```

Would become

```
sf::RectangleShape typeArea;
```

**EDIT: After fixing these things, I did some debugging:**

```
error: class 'Textbox' has no member named 'setFont';
```

This is true. When you call .setFont(); on your instance passCreate, you are not calling .setFont(); from SFML, but .setFont(); in your class Textbox -- Which doesn't exist. Adding this to your class solved this problem.

```
void setFont(sf::Font font){
    textbox.setFont(font);
};
```

This essentially takes the font you pass it, and applies it to the instance's textbox you called setFont(); on.

The compiler also complains that textbox.setLimit(bool, int) has no candidate. You are  passing it a bool *AND* integer right now. This is because your function setLimit() inside class Textbox does not have an integer passthrough.
I changed

```
void setLimit(bool tof){
    hasLimit = tof;
}
```

to

```
void setLimit(bool tof, int setlimit){
    hasLimit = tof;
    limit = setlimit;
}
```

Where setLimit now takes the integer you are sending it, and assigns it to the integer variable "limit" inside your class Textbox.

After this, there are no more compiler errors. I will leave the rest to you! Troubleshooting can be fun. Just look at what the compiler says. It will tell you what is wrong.
[image]

**Last tips:**
Might'n't I also add that entering an incorrect password does not stop me from 'logging in';
When the console asks me for my password, the main screen shows up as frozen. Perhaps you can set a blanking sprite to cover everything instead? I'm sure there's better solutions though!

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the errors but the RectangleShape is still not showing up for some reason

Answer (score -1):

Try including <SFML/Graphics.hpp>